# Regex String Search Problem

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to fetch specific URLs from a Large String.

http://www.rubular.com/r/OYxQHVTWfF

The same URLs I can extract from Web Interface. 
But the same RegEx pattern is not working in iPhone SDK.

I tried with it , so many times. 
I am trying with nsregularexpression.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
        @"\"low_resolution\"[:][\\s]{\"url\"[:][\\s]\"([^\"]*)"
```

Please help out.

Comment: what do you except? what do you get? try to describe the problem with some more examples.

Comment: does iphone regular expression flavor is the same as ruby ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to extract URL from that data blob, then this regex pattern will do just fine on most regex engines:

```
low_resolution": {"url": "([^"]+)"
```

You just retreive 1st backreference...

Note: If you use double quotes inside string, use single quotes around it, so you wont need to escape double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the `{`:

```
@"\"low_resolution\":\\s\\{\"url\":\\s\"([^\"]*)"
```